# Problem with Coordinate Tolerances when I export my .shp files to .mdb

Tags: shapefile, esri-geodatabase, import, resolution, personal-geodatabase

[image]

When I export my shapefile to a personal geodatabase using ArcMap, the result is not the same as the original database. I do not know how to solve this problem.

Comment: What exactly was your process?  Your question is not clear.  Were you importing a shapefile to a PGDB using ArcMap?

Comment: Strange thing, i am working with PGDB a lot and there is no such problem. Please mention ArcGIS verion and type of PGDB and if possible upload subset of data.

Comment: Answer                                                     PGDP- Featuredataset- Edit projection - import- shapefile

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible that there is something wrong with resolution and tolerance in PGDB.

Take a look at sections **X,y resolution** and **X,y tolerance** in [this topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000005000000).

Try increasing these values.

What coordinate system are you using? What values are set for resolution and tolerance?

Comment: Used on Geographic Coordinates: GCS WGS 1984, im not set resolution and tolerant

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may be having an issue with the [resolution](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n0000001v000000) setting of your Feature Dataset.  Since you are using a Feature Dataset, you need to set an appropriate XY Tolerance, as mentioned in step 7 of the article "[Creating a feature dataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_feature_dataset/002300000002000000/)".  By default the XY tolerance should be sufficient (and in the case of WGS84, the resolution units are degrees).  As [this article](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w0000000r000000) states:

> For tools like Create Feature Class, Create Feature Dataset, and
>   Create Raster Catalog, the default x,y tolerance for the output
>   geodataset is 0.001 meters (1 millimeter) or its equivalent in map
>   units. This environment can be set to a different value if the default
>   is not acceptable.

If needed, though, try reducing the XY Tolerance to meet your needs.  The last panel of the wizard allows you to set the XY, Z, and M tolerance.